# Quantum computing with biological matter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, biophysics

As a biologist with physics background I wonder whether there is a way to use biological matter to create quantum computers or at least to advance the field somewhat. Usually, my first feeling would be "No", since decoherence times are much too quick at room temperature, but I found two articles

"Terahertz radiation induces non-thermal structural changes associated with Fröhlich condensation in a protein crystal" (http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/222899/local_222899.pdf), which shows Bose-Einstein condensate-like structures in biological matter at room temparature,

and

"The role of non-equilibrium vibrational structures in electronic coherence and recoherence in pigment–protein complexes" (http://www3.physik.uni-stuttgart.de/TR21/common/show_file.php/publications/945/publication.pdf), which shows long coherence times in some protein complexes.

These two articles challenge that point of view a bit. I am wondering whether you could imagine that there is some suitable way of using such matter for it and how that could be tested? As a biologist, one way could be to mutate the protein sequences such that their performance gets enhanced/mutated/controllable.

Comment: There is a similar situation in the fiction series _The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy_ where a pan-dimensional alien race creates Earth as a very big organic computer to find the question to the answer _42._

Comment: My comment to the first paper would be that whenever someone needs a complex system (why use a protein crystal?) to demonstrate a claimed physical effect that has escaped detection on much simpler ones for decades, the correct reaction would be to say "Bold claims require bold data, not subtle data with handwaving in an open access journal that doesn't have any history of high quality publications and peer review.". The second paper looks a lot better and the folks in Stuttgart are actually known for quality work. That paper is a lot more solid, but it doesn't do what you want. In general: NO

Comment: @CuriousOne That should be an answer.

Comment: @CuriousOne Many thanks for your comment! But if we assume that paper no. 1 is valid (despite that might be false), would there be a possibility to somehow harness these results/proteins for the use of some kind of quantum computation?

Comment: I am not assuming anything, I simply like high quality evidence and explanations. I am also not much into the "Hey, let's use X to do Y." approach to engineering. If you have a goal (in this case it's quantum computing, isn't it?), use whatever approach is the most likely to get you there, don't add unnecessary constrains like "...but it has to use something that looks like a biological system...". A protein crystal is not even a biological system, to begin with.

Comment: Cross-posted to engineering: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7042/quantum-computing-with-biological-matter

Comment: All I can see is that researchers from the EMBL, the University of Gothenborg and the Chalmers University of Technology are involved, which are all good institutions, and the last author is known researcher in structural biology, so to me that gives some credibility to it. In the end it is always an "assumption", whether or not I do believe the content of a paper, and I would say that is definitely possible here.

Comment: A structural biologist doesn't lend credibility to a physics paper any more than a physics degree lends credibility to claims about global warming (I happen to know a physicist who got himself egged badly trying that trick a couple years ago). Good institutions also don't mean a thing and everybody can be wrong about anything at all times without any warning in science. That's why we have peer review. The peer reviewer is the last person on Earth who can, if he/she cares, save your scientific reputation. Avoiding him/her is a bad idea and so is publishing in a new and untested "open" journal.

Comment: As for the ultimate answer to the paper's claims: experimental papers can only be validated by repeating the experiments and by augmenting them with controls that the original authors didn't have. Unless you are willing to embark on a multi-year research effort to do just that, you will not get your answer if what they authors claim is real or not. No amount of soul searching on the internet or claims about the author's credibility has any weight in science. Do the experiment and see what you get. Along the way you will, most likely, pick up on the trivial mistakes that these authors made.

Comment: Related: [Seth Lloyd on Quantum Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcXSpXyZVuY) (on life using quantum effects, e.g. photosynthesis using a quantum walk). And this talk is 100X better than that TED talk about the same thing.

Comment: emergent effects looking like quantum mechanics are common with fluids ans vibrations. Remember the rogue waves : quantum interpretation lasted a while ...